# Помогите мне извлечь src из img JSOUP

Tags: android, jsoup

Помогите мне извлечь src из img. Есть html структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне получить доступ к li div.th img. Пробовал достать через .select, но дальше div.th он ничего не видит (если снова делать select, иначе же выводит нужный код: img и div).

Объяснение кодом для тех, кто не понял:

```
    Elements elements = main_document.select("ul.search-results li");
    
        for(Element element : elements){
            Elements el = element.select("div.th");
    
            Log.v("HTML Parse", el.get(0).html());
        }   
LOG ПРИ select("div.th"): 
    V/HTML Parse: <img src="/i/book/19/12/16134.jpg" width="383" height="570" alt="">
LOG ПРИ select("div.th img"): 
    (пустота)
```

Comment: не нужно лепить метку `android-studio` в вопросах не связанных с IDE!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все получилось:

```
Elements li = main_document.select("ul.search-results li");
Book book_instance = new Book();
        
for(Element element : li){
    Elements images = element.select("div.th img");
    String img = images.first().attr("src");
        
    Elements titles = element.select("p.book-tooltip a");
    String title = titles.first().text();
        
    book_instance.setImage(img);
    book_instance.setTranslate_title(title);
        
    getBooks().add(book_instance);
}
```